# counting the number of rows in a db table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find the number of rows in a table and have tried the following:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE DIR='$dir'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

but i get the following warning when the script is run

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given

any ideas?

Comment: your mixing mysql and mysqli and procedural vs oop

Comment: Try, `mysqli`_num_rows, you are using `mysql`_num_rows

Comment: mysqli may return different type than mysql.  If you want to use `mysql_num_rows()`, use `mysql_query()`.

Comment: using mysql_num_rows i get:   mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: you cant just add an **i**, the syntax is different, and your still mixing procedural  with oop

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.